# Как вывести коинтеграцию через adfuller()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Для вывода коинтеграции я использую этот метод:

```
def check_list_for_cointegration(X, Y):
    coint_t = ts.coint(X, Y)[1]
    return coint_t
```

затем мне надо вывести коинтеграцию использую adfuller()

```
def dickey_fuller(X, Y):
   ols_result = sm.OLS(X, Y).fit()
   return ts.adfuller(ols_result.resid)[1]
```

При выводи p-value отличается

Comment: Вы можете привести пример входных и выходных данных?

Comment: По ссылки входные и выходные данные 
первый результат это по coint(), второй по adfuller()
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxs_Ni2VLVbQZmxJeXZtNndvakU

Comment: Т.е. Первый столбец это X , второй-Y?

Comment: да, и в конце ответы

Comment: А чем не устраивает `ts.coint()`? По-моему это все-таки немного разные тесты...

Comment: Просто задача поставлена вывести двумя способами и посмотреть погрешность.